# Proofread matrix multiply inverse of matrix are unique

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove $\textbf{A}^{-1}$ is unique for $\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^{-1} = \textbf{I}$

Assume 
$$\textbf{B} \neq \textbf{A}^{-1} \text{ and }\textbf{A}\textbf{B} = \textbf{I}$$
$$\textbf{A}\textbf{A}^{-1} = \textbf{I}$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{A}\textbf{A}^{-1} - \textbf{I} = \textbf{0}$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{A}\textbf{A}^{-1} - \textbf{A}\textbf{B} = \textbf{0}$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{A}(\textbf{A}^{-1} - \textbf{B})=\textbf{0}$$
$$\because (\textbf{A}^{-1}-\textbf{B}) \neq \textbf{0}$$
$$\therefore\text{matrix}\ (\textbf{A}^{-1}-\textbf{B})\ \text{contains at lease one column vector }\vec{v}_i \neq 0, \text{otherwise the matrix is zero matrix}$$
$$\text{let } \textbf{A}^{-1} - \textbf{B}=\lbrack\vec{v}_0, \vec{v}_1...\vec{v}_i...\vec{v}_n\rbrack$$
$$\textbf{A}\lbrack\vec{v}_0,\vec{v}_1...\vec{v}_i...\vec{v}_n\rbrack = \textbf{0}$$
$$\lbrack\textbf{A}\vec{v}_0,\textbf{A}\vec{v}_1...\textbf{A}\vec{v}_i...\textbf{A}\vec{v}_n\rbrack=\textbf{0}\tag{1}$$
$$\because \textbf{A}\text{ is invertible and }\vec{v}_i \neq \vec{0}$$
$$\therefore \textbf{A}\vec{v}_i \neq \vec{0}$$
$$\text{But }\vec{A}\vec{v}_i = \vec{0} \text{ from }\text{(1)} $$
$$\text{This contracts our assumption which is }\textbf{A}^{-1} \neq \textbf{B}$$
$$\Rightarrow \textbf{A}^{-1} = \textbf{B}$$
$$\textbf{Therefore }\textbf{A}^{-1}\text{ is unique}$$

Comment: Is it generally true that $AB=0$ implies $A=0$ or $B=0$?

Comment: I don't think this proof suffices where you state $\Rightarrow \textbf{A}\textbf{A}^{-1} - \textbf{A}\textbf{B} = \textbf{0}$ you cannot conclude that $A\neq 0$.

Comment: @user60887 Actually, it looks like $\because$ means "because" and it's being used to derive the next line. At first glance I confused it with "therefore" ($\therefore$), thinking the same thing you were. It just goes to show that proving things with long strings of symbols is not really the best method of expressing oneself.

Comment: What we need to do is this: (a) describe the setting, i.e. that $A$ is a square matrix and t.e. some $B$ of similar dimensions such that $AB=I$. (b) explain why $B$ has a right-inverse. (c) use that right-inverse of $B$ to prove that $BA=I$ as well. (d) use that fact to conclude the proof, since then $A(C-B)=0$ really does imply $B=C$.

Comment: I changed $B\ne A^{-1}\  and\  AB=I$ to $B\ne A^{-1}\text{ and }AB=I$.  Note that \text{ and } is part of the code.  You don't need to manually insert spacing between words, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The justifcation does not hold:

> "from $A(A^{-1}-B)=0$ and $A\neq 0$, it follows $A^{-1}-B=0$"

A proper justification would be

> Since $A(A^{-1}-B)=0$ and $A$ is *nonsingular*, then $A^{-1}-B=0$.

This presupposes that you understand why $A$ is nonsingular and know that it makes a 1-1 mapping, though!

Comment: I think I should said $\because \mathbb{A}^{-1} \neq \mathbb{B}\therefore \mathbb{A}^{-1} - \mathbb{B} \neq 0$\\

Comment: Need a little more argument to show that, just update my proof, thanks

Comment: $\text{Still it is not obvious for me if }\textbf{A}(\textbf{A}^{-1}-\textbf{B})\text{ and }\textbf{A}\text{ is nonsingular, then }\textbf{A}^{-1} - \textbf{B} = \textbf{0}\text{ without the fact }\textbf{A} \text{ is nonsingular and }\textbf{A}\vec{v}=\vec{0}\text{ if and only if } \vec{v}=\vec{0}$

Comment: Then you should multiply $A(A^{-1}-B)=0$ on the left on both sides by $A^{-1}$, getting the result.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to give a counterexample, to give you a feel why the above is not precise enough.

You say:

> Prove $A^{−1}$ is unique for $AA^{−1} = I$.

This reads:

> We denote $A^{-1} := B$ for $B$ such that $AB = I$. Prove that such $B$ is unique.

Now, let

$$A := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad B := \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \end{bmatrix}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Then

$$AB = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ x \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \end{bmatrix} = I,$$

for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so such $B$ is not unique.

You're missing the condition that $A$ is nonsingular, or that $A$ is square, or that $A^{-1}$ is both left and right inverse, or... But the way you put it, the statement is false and, hence, cannot be proven.

Comment: well, $\mathbb{A}$ is square is understood and $\mathbb{A}\mathbb{A}^{-1} = \mathbb{I}$

Comment: It was not written. So, if it's square, you need to use that fact somehow, because without that fact the statement is - as I've shown - wrong and thus unprovable.

Comment: If your prof ask you to inverse a matrix, do you really need to ask whether the matrix is square or not? because you can't inverse the non square matrix.

Comment: This is besides the point. If you don't use the fact, then your statement doesn't need it. Why would you ask for $A$ to be square if you can do the proof without that fact? But, if $A$ is square and $AB = I$, then $B$ is square as well (since $I$ is square of the same order as $A$). Now, if either $A$ or $B$ is singular, then it is easy to show that $AB$ is singular as well, which is a contradiction (since $I$ is nonsingular). So, $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular, so $A$ has left and right inverse. We still don't know that they are the same, but you can use the fact that both of them exist.

Comment: From your counterexample, you argue about the notation $$\textbf{A}^{-1}\ \text{is not inverse of matrix } \textbf{A}$$

Comment: It's not, until you prove it is. I called it $B$ to make it less confusing. You can put $A^{-1}$ instead of $B$ in my counterexample, and everything would remain the same. The problem is that you see $A^{-1}$ and treat it like an inverse, with all its properties... while trying to prove one of those properties. That's why it's less confusing to say "we have $B$ such that <whatever you want>" and then try to prove what you need. Only when you have that for a nonsingular there is a unique $B$ such that $AB = BA = I$, you can call that $B$ <i><b>the</b> inverse</i> and denote it as $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, I got your point now, Thanks to point that out.